# Can you create a colorbox slideshow for a set of divs?

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

So in colorbox photos can be grouped together to form a slideshow, I would like to be able to use divs as the content of the slideshow instead of images. Is that supported?

Javascript code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("div.colorbox").colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true,slideshow: true, href: function () {
             var elementID = $(this).find('div .pop').attr('id');
             return "#" + elementID;
          }
     });
   </script>
```

Html/Css is:

```
<div class="colorbox" >Div #1
         <div style="display:none">
          <div id="Div1" class="pop">
             Data#1 inside div
          </div>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="colorbox" >Div #2
         <div style="display:none">
          <div id="Div2" class="pop">
             Data#2 inside div
          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas if this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by doing

```
$("div.colorbox").colorbox({rel:"my_group"})
```