# How to display multiple divs in Colorbox as a slideshow?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, colorbox

Say I have a list of divs identified by class .e.g '.myclass'

Inside each div will be some html content rather than an image.
How do I go about opening the colorbox() so that on clicking the arrows, they will flick through the divs?

I looked at the following post which is the same problem, but his solution gives me no clue as to how he got it working: [Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832285/can-you-create-a-colorbox-slideshow-for-a-set-of-divs)

Is colorbox even the correct plugin for this?

Comment: I flushed out my comment into a proper implementation.  I know you already accepted an answer, but I suggest you switch out your implementation....  See my post update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best I could get it.  I had to group it with 'rel', and call colorBox once for each div that you wanted to group.

http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/rc5m7/

**UPDATE**

I've updated the base fiddle above to Adam's solution.  He uses `.each` and `.find` nicely to allow iterating through divs of the same className rather than by unique id.  You can see my original solution here:  http://jsfiddle.net/rc5m7/13/

Comment: @Adam Terlson Agreed, +1 to your answer.  Updated my base fiddle to your solution.  Others can still see my original solution at http://jsfiddle.net/rc5m7/13/.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE:

I know you already accepted an answer, but here's a much cleaner approach than the currently accepted answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/rc5m7/14/

HTML:

```
<div class="colorbox">Div #1
    <div style="display:none">
            Data#1 inside div.  This is just a test.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="colorbox">Div #2
    <div style="display:none">
            Data#2 inside div.  This is just a test.
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.colorbox').each(function() {
        $(this).colorbox({
            html: $(this).find('div').html(),
            rel: 'group_1'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried their example, but it only shows one div being used. If I try to replace the inline html with multiple Divs and a class attribute instead, it doesn't work. It still displays all divs rather than as a slide-show. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried having more than one div with the class of "example8"?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me perfectly - prefered to keep inline content all together. Just make sure you use the latest Colorbox version (currently 1.3.19).

```
<a class="info_link" rel="help_msg1" href="#">Need help 1?</a>
<a class="info_link" rel="help_msg2" href="#">Need help 2?</a>

<div style="display: none;">
    <div id='help_msg1'>
        Help message 1 goes here
    </div>
    <div id='help_msg2'>
        Help message 2 goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS looks like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".info_link").colorbox({    
      width:"50%",
      inline: true,
      href: function () { return '#'+$(this).attr('rel') }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow on from Adam's solution, you can actually supply functions as settings parameters, which would mean you wouldn't have to use an `each()` which can sometimes be a little power hungry.

HTML:

```
<div class="colorbox">Div #1
    <div style="display:none">
            Data#1 inside div.  This is just a test.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="colorbox">Div #2
    <div style="display:none">
            Data#2 inside div.  This is just a test.
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.colorbox').colorbox({
        html: function() { return $(this).find('div').html(); },
        rel: 'group_1'
    });
});
```